# How to make fast capacitive touch buttons without a microcontroller

Tags: multiplexer, frequency-measurement

(I have already read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516906/how-to-make-fast-low-latency-capacitive-touch-buttons).)

I am looking to make a musical instrument with a series of capacitive buttons in a grid of 17x4 buttons, with a length of about two feet and a width of three inches.  Due to (A) the number of buttons and (B) the mechanical design of the instrument I am hesitant to use a microcontroller.  I will have a microcontroller at one end of the grid to process the touches, but finding a MCU with 68 leftover GPIOs is hard enough, let alone 68 timers.  Much like in the linked question, off-the-shelf ICs created for capacitive sensing are much to slow for my purposes.  The ideal solution will have a latency of less than 1 ms.

I was thinking of using some sort of oscillator whose frequency can be affected by the capacitance of my finger, along with some sort of counter, but that leaves me with a very serious multiplexing problem.  I don't have a lot of space--68 counters seems like a lot of counters, and regardless, that still leaves me with the same problem, counters outputting pulses that a microcontroller needs to analyze.

Comment: Back in the 80s, microcontrollers were running at few MHz and had only a couple of timers, yet they managed to make e.g. 61 key synths that are velocity sensitive with 1 or 2 timers. You have 100x the horsepower and more timers, but you don't need a hardware timer per key just like in the 80's. Also capacitive touch sensors are slow, because they need the time for multiple readings to reliably detect small capacitance changes of e.g. finger while still being able to ignore small changes in capacitance due to humidity.

Comment: Can you please provide a cutout drawing of the physical sensor areas? I have problems to imagine a useful grid of 17 x 4 sensors arranged in a two feet x three inches area.

Comment: I'm taking some inspiration from [this](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Kitara--misa-digital-kitara).  The 17x4 buttons is the fretboard.  I can't really put too much inside the next without compromising the structural integrity, so ideally every 2 frets (4 strings each) would have their own sensor, which would all get multiplexed (rounding up to 18 isn't a problem).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a microcontroller, there are stand-alone touch sensors available.

Or if you you want to build your own, instead of measuring frequency, measure an analogue property like power consumption, or amplitude.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOuaNY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

74lvc1g08 under 5c in quantity. almost as cheap as the transistor.

Obvously don't use a pot but instead choose the apropriate resistor for the sensitivity you want, which will depend on the capacitance of your touch pads.

125Khz chosen because it's an ISM band.
Emitted radiatrion can be reduced by using half inverting and half non-inverting gates,

Comment: Most off-the-shelf touch sensors have an unacceptably high latency.

Comment: How do you guarantee that Vee of the OR gate doesn't exceed 0.5 V?  Most transistors have a turn-on Vbe of around 0.7 V.  Seems like you would destroy the gate before the transistor even turns on.

Comment: Not stated above the square wave doesn't go to 0V to 5V only to about 1v to 5v , Vee of the or gate is kept low by the 10K (or whatever resistance is suitable there - which will depend on the capacitive load the gate  is driving)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you think could destroy the gate (unless you were thinking of  the clock signal flowing below VEE, adding some resistance between the gate and the touch pad will reduce emitted noise too.  how much depends on the sensitivity needed.

Answer (score 0):

68 timers and GPIOs I’m not so sure about, but 64 high-functionality smart GPIO pins is very much a solved problem.

[Parallax Propeller 2 (P2X8C4M64P)](https://www.parallax.com/propeller-2/) chip has all of that. It has identical I/O on each pin, so you got 64 8-bit DACs, ADCs, comparators, complex double timers, so on and so forth. Stick two of them and it will do just about anything you need and then some. It’s a very powerful part. There are a couple of lower-cost carrier boards for it.

Development, in a pinch, can be done without any special software. It comes with a FORTH interpreter in the bottom if you feel adventurous :) It’s a perfect pastime if all you got is a bit of power, a serial terminal, a notebook (paper kind), P2, and time to pass in a cabin in the mountains :)